# Diference in getResource between Jetty and Tomcat produces file not found exception

Tags: java, tomcat, resources, jetty, filenotfoundexception

I'm using the following code to look up resource needed for Freemarker to create PDFs from HTML.

```
public static URL lookupResource(String resource) {
    System.out.println("Looking up resource: " + resource);
    ClassLoader classLoader =  Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();      
    URL templateFileUrl = classLoader.getResource(resource);        
    System.out.println("path: " + templateFileUrl.getPath());   
    return templateFileUrl;
}
```

Running on Jetty in an Eclipse Maven project I get the following:

```
Looking up resource: abc.html
path: /C:/Projects/WebDocs/EclipseProjects/webdocs2/webdocs/target/classes/abc.xhtml
```

This is where the resource is and works fine.

When I export a war file to Tomcat the resources are put in 
/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%207.0/webapps/webdocs

Running on Tomcat I get the following:

```
Looking up resource: abc.html
path: /C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%207.0/webapps/webdocs/WEB-INF/classes/abc.xhtml
```

This is not where the resoures are and results in a file not found exception.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you should be:

- using [`ServletContext.getResource("/abc.html")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) to access content from within a WebApp.
- not be using `/WEB-INF/classes/` to store static resources.  Use `/WEB-INF/resources/`

As the webapp container can move content around to suit its own needs.

(see javadoc on [`javax.servlet.ServletContext.getResource(String path)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) for details)

Also, the utility class should not be relying on `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()`.  Instead, use the classloader obtained from the class that is requesting the resource.

```java
public class MyClass {
  public void doIt() {
    URL url = Utils.getResource(this,"abc.html");
  }
}

public final class Utils {
  public static URL getResource(Object obj, String resource) {
    return obj.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(resource);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This may work in a Web container, but the code is not necessarily always running inside a servlet container all the time, and the utility class that provides the resource does not have access to the ServletContext. I could pass the ServletContext through a chain of methods to the utility class, or use a thread local variable, but there is another problem. The code needs to run in stand alone programs and in unit tests that do not run in a web container. It just need an html template and a Map to produce PDF output.

Comment: Then don't put the resource in `/WEB-INF/classes/`, put the resource in a jar file found in `/WEB-INF/lib/`.  That way you will gain maximum compatibility.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Please provide the complete solution

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I am doing like this:                                                              public static int EMP_LEDGER = 6;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
private static String EMP_LEDGER_PATH ="\\employee_ledger\\EmployeeLedger.jasper";                                                   case 6:return getParentDir() + EMP_LEDGER_PATH;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store templates (or any other resource) as a part of your jar, I would review the code to use InputStreams instead. To obtain template, use `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()` (or even better, `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream()` and organize resources in package structure). After that, use contructor `Template(InputStream stream)` to construct the template. This way, your code will work even in situations when your jar/war is not "exploded" into physical files.

To use `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream()`, your resource will have to be in a same directory when compiled into jar as a class file. If you use maven, put resource in *"resources/path/to/yourpackage/resource.file"*. Note: a safer way is to use class name itself for this solution, for example, MyClass.getResourceAsStream(), as often this.getClass() won't work in subclassing or autoproxying scenarios.